# Xamarin: Unable to open the project with Method not found: System.__CanonEnumerator.NameAndPassword

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, project, methodnotfound

I am trying to open a project pulled from the SourceTree and opened up with Xamarin. It was a Xamarin.Form project. Somehow I received this error:

[image]

Does anybody come across this problem.

Comment: Fixed: I have to update the xamarin studio to the latest

Comment: Since you resolved this issue, it would be a good idea to answer it yourself and mark it as answered so others don't stop on this thinking it is still an open question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry didn't realize i can answer my own question and marked it as answer.. I tried to find an option to mark it but can't find it so that is why I added the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Install latest xamarin fixed my own problem